# How do I sort List in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How do I sort List of id and name where name is sort alphabetically.

```
List employees = [
    [1, "Deshawn O'Connell"],
    [2, "Aurore Kuvalis"],
    [3, "Louvenia Rapid"],
    [4, "Missouri Crooks"],
    [5, "Kylie Krajcik Jr."]
  ];
```

So that I get the output as

```
    [2, "Aurore Kuvalis"],
    [1, "Deshawn O'Connell"],
    [5, "Kylie Krajcik Jr."],
    [3, "Louvenia Rapid"],
    [4, "Missouri Crooks"],
```

Comment: Yes it worked as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `sort` function of the `List` and pass in a sorting function that compares the second element(index 1) of each sublist.

```dart
void main() {
  List employees = [
    [1, "Deshawn O'Connell"],
    [2, "Aurore Kuvalis"],
    [3, "Louvenia Rapid"],
    [4, "Missouri Crooks"],
    [5, "Kylie Krajcik Jr."]
  ];
  employees.sort((list1, list2) => list1[1].compareTo(list2[1]));
  print(employees);
}

//Output:
//[[2, Aurore Kuvalis], [1, Deshawn O'Connell], [5, Kylie Krajcik Jr.], [3, Louvenia Rapid], [4, Missouri Crooks]]
```